# Error de Stream al invocar un servicio REST en Spring MVC con dos objetos javascript

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

Saludos estoyr intentando pasar como parametro dos objetos JSON a un metodo REST que se encuentra en un una API rest en `Spring MVC`, ando usando un servicio de tipo factory en `AngularJS` para hacer la llamada al metodo.

El servidor me responde con un error 500 con este mensaje

```
Could not read document: Stream closed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

El metodo funcionaba correctamente cuando le pasaba un solo objeto de tipo JSON, pero al modificarlo para que recibiera dos objetos de tipo JSON ocasiono que pasaa este error.

Este es mi servicio de tipo factory en AngularJS
aqui le paso dos parametros de tipo JSON uno llamado cliente y otro contacto
cuando solo pasa cliente el metodo si funcionaba.

```
createCliente: function (cliente, contacto) {
                            return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/MySpringMVCApp/cliente/', cliente, contacto)
                                    .then(
                                            function (response) {
                                                console.log('Inside Cliente-Servicio createCliente');

                                                return response.data;
                                            },
                                            function (errResponse) {
                                                console.error('Error ' + errResponse);
                                                return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                            }
                                    );
                        }
```

aqui esta el metodo del backend en spring lo adapte para q reciiera dos parameros

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/cliente/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createCliente(@RequestBody Cliente cliente, @RequestBody Contacto contacto, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/cliente/{id}").buildAndExpand(cliente.getIdCliente()).toUri());
    System.out.println("headers vale " + headers);
    clienteDAO.insertarCliente(cliente);
    Integer ultimoIdCliente = clienteDAO.buscarUltimoIdClienteEnBDporNombreCliente(cliente.getNombre());
    contactoDAO.insertarContactoCliente(contacto, ultimoIdCliente);

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

pero el servidor retorna este error `Could not read document: Stream closed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

**EDIT:**
 Revise y el error era que solo se puede pasar una variable de tipo @RequestBody pero no estoy muy seguro si es cierto, asi que cambie el controlador de la siguiente forma

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cliente/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createCliente(@RequestBody Cliente cliente, String contactoJSON, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
Contacto contactoParseado = new ObjectMapper().readValue(contacto, Contacto.class);
}
```

Y luego de que tengo el contactoJSON lo intento parsear al objeto con una libreira, el problema es que contactoJSON llega `null` esta llega sin ningun valor y me da la exception nullpointer exception, como podria pasar este String json al controlador para luego parsearlo a mi tipo de objeto

yo ando llamando al metodo del backend asi desde angulajs

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/MySpringMVCApp/cliente/', cliente, contacto)
```

pero no veo cual seria el error

**EDIT2**
Edite el metodo factory de la siguiente forma

```
createCliente: function (cliente, contacto) {
                    var data = {
                        "cliente": cliente,
                        "contacto": contacto
                    };

                    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTemplateAnn/cliente/', data)
                            .then(
                             //resto codigo
```

y a ese servicio factory le paso los siguiente objetos

```
var clienteJSON = {
                    idCliente: 0,
                    nombre: cliente.nombre,
                    alias: cliente.alias,
                    listaContacto: null,
                    listaPersonaContacto: null
                };
 var contactoJSON = {
                    idContacto: 0,
                    idCliente: 0,
                    idPersonaContacto: 0,
                    ubicacion: contacto.ubicacion,
                    numeroTelefono: contacto.numeroTelefono,
                    email: contacto.email,
                    paginaWeb: contacto.paginaWeb,
                    rif: contacto.rif
                };
```

los objetos se llenan satisfactoriamente con los datos del frontend

metodo backend

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cliente/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createCliente(@RequestBody Map<String, String> datos, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

    System.out.println("contacto JSON vale: " + datos);
    System.out.println("cliente JSON vale: " + datos);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    try {
        Cliente clienteParseado = new ObjectMapper().readValue(datos.get("cliente"), Cliente.class);
        Contacto contactoParseado = new ObjectMapper().readValue(datos.get("contacto"), Contacto.class);
```

Estos son los objetos Json que recibe el metodo backend

mi contacto json

```
({idContacto:0, idCliente:0, idPersonaContacto:0, ubicacion:"contactoUbicacionValor", numeroTelefono:"contactoTelefonoValor", email:"contactoEmailValor", paginaWeb:"contactoPagiaValor", rif:"contactoRifValor"})
```

mi cliente json

```
({idCliente:0, nombre:"nombreDelClienteValor", alias:"AliasDelClienteValor", listaContacto:null, listaPersonaContacto:null})
```

y mi Map

```
({cliente:{idCliente:0, nombre:"nombreDelClienteValor", alias:"AliasDelClienteValor", listaContacto:null, listaPersonaContacto:null}, contacto:{idContacto:0, idCliente:0, idPersonaContacto:0, ubicacion:"contactoUbicacionValor", numeroTelefono:"contactoTelefonoValor", email:"contactoEmailValor", paginaWeb:"contactoPagiaValor", rif:"contactoRifValor"}})
```

Estas son las clases de los objetos en java

MI calse Clase Cliente

```
public class Cliente {

private Integer idCliente;
private String nombre;
private String alias;
private List<Contacto> listaContacto;
private List<PersonaContacto> listaPersonaContacto;
```

MI clase Contacto

```
public class Contacto {

private Integer idContacto;
private Integer idCliente;
private Integer idPersonaContacto;
private String ubicacion;
private String tipo;
private String numeroTelefono;
private String email;
private String paginaWeb;
private String rif;
```

luego de haber realizado las moificaciones el servidor me retrorna este error

```
    Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2f3ab7f1; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["cliente"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2f3ab7f1; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["cliente"])
```

Sospecho que podria ser porque mi clase cliente posee atributos que son tipo `List` y cuando los seteo en null cuando armo el objeto esto podria causar algun error es mi sospecha.

Comment: Coloca tu llamado al webservice (el JSON que estás enviando), de plano no vas a poder enviar varios objetos a tu servicio porque tu `RequestBody` es de un objeto `Cliente`

Comment: Saludos edite mi pregunta, en resumen al mandar un solo `@RequestBody` este bloquea todos los parametros asi los otros paremtros sean de distintos tipos de datos? es decir si mando un `@RequestBody` y de seungo parametro mando un `String` y de tercer parametro mando un  `UriComponentsBuilder`, por haber mandado un RequestBody los otros parametros son null? entiendo si mando varios `requestbody`pase eso , pero por mandar uno solo no creo que afecte los demas paramtros

Comment: Yo te diría que recibas un String y luego ese String lo mapearas manualmente, pierdes el mapeo automático de Spring? si, pero te va a permitir trabajar con datos más "customizados" si esa es tu necesidad.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes mandar dos objetos a través de una petición REST. Spring leerá el contenido de 1 primero y luego cerrará el stream del cuerpo del contenido de la petición, por ello cuando tenga que leer el segundo objeto, puesto que el stream está cerrado, no puede leerlo y sale esta excepción. Esto no es una limitación de Spring, sino algo natural que puede suceder en cualquier otra tecnología incluso ajena a Java.

Si necesitas enviar más información hacia el servidor, lo mejor sería enviar 1 solo objeto que contenga la información de tus dos o más entidades, y de lado del servidor separarlas convenientemente.

En caso que quieras parsear los objetos String manualmente desde Spring, puedes hacerlo así.

De lado del cliente:

```
createCliente: function (cliente, contacto) {
    var data = {
        "cliente" : cliente,
        "contacto" : contacto
    };
    return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/MySpringMVCApp/cliente/', data)
    //resto del código...
}
```

De lado del servidor:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cliente/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createCliente(@RequestBody Map<String, String> datos, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    //esto es básico, debes mejorarlo
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Cliente cliente = objectMapper.readValue(datos.get("cliente"), Cliente.class);
    Contacto contacto = objectMapper.readValue(datos.get("contacto"), Contacto.class);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/cliente/{id}").buildAndExpand(cliente.getIdCliente()).toUri());
    System.out.println("headers vale " + headers);
    clienteDAO.insertarCliente(cliente);
    Integer ultimoIdCliente = clienteDAO.buscarUltimoIdClienteEnBDporNombreCliente(cliente.getNombre());
    contactoDAO.insertarContactoCliente(contacto, ultimoIdCliente);

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: saludos edite mi pregunta sin haber leido antes tu respuesta parace que fue al mismo tiempo, gracias por tu respuesta amigo, habira alguna forma de mandar un solo  `@RequestBody ` y el segundo objeto mandar un string normal y luego parsear este string? Intente declarando el segundo parametro como String pero este llega null al mtodo

Comment: @Bill_Data23 no. Una vez que Spring consume el cuerpo del contenido de la petición para mapearlo a `@RequestBody`, se cierra el stream y no se puede leer más. Necesitas enviar un solo objeto con toda la información relevante.

Comment: @Bill_Data23 acabo de actualizar mi respuesta.

Comment: edite mi pregunta segun tus sugerencias pero ahora tengo un nuevo error

Comment: @Bill_Data23 parece que el contenido JSON que envías no puede ser mapeado a un objeto de tu clase `Cliente`. Esto no es parte fundamental del problema en concreto que publicaste en la pregunta. Te recomiendo que: 1) Si mi respuesta te ayudó, la marques como aceptada porque resuelve tu problema de mapeo de entidades (si no te ayudó, no la marques) 2) Publiques una **nueva pregunta** con el nuevo error que tienes sobre el mapeo de Jackson, en la nueva pregunta agrega toda la información para reproducir el problema: la cadena, la estructura de la clase, etc.

Comment: Saludos Luiggi aprecio mucho tu ayuda, me parecio una buena idea la forma simplificada de pasar los objetos Json en dentro de un Map y luego parcearlos en Jakcson en el backend ando investigando mas sobre el error para hacerlo funcionar si no pasare un solo JSON fuera del map, soy nuevo en el sitio y no se si iria contra las reglas hacer dos preguntas con un contenido muy similar solo que con titulos diferentes, es posible cambiar el titulo de la pregunta? ya edite los datos necesarios para que los lectores puedan tener mas informacion del nuevo error.